# Suddenly get "apt-get: symbol lookup error" when using apt-get

Tags: ubuntu-8.04

I have no idea what has gone wrong here. I have installed the audiotool sox, then tried to install the library libsox-fmt-all and all of a sudden apt-get refused to work. I cannot use it now, neither to update nor to install anything. Could somebody suggest what i could do to get it back to work? Here is the complete message it throws:

```
apt-get: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: undefined symbol: _ZNSt7num_getIcSt19istreambuf_iteratorIcSt11char_traitsIcEEE2idE, version GLIBCXX_3.4
```

Comment: were you able to fixed this problem?

Answer (score 1):

First of all: check your filesystem for errors.

Then try reinstalling libstdc++.so.6 with dpkg.
Therefore you may want to download libstdc++6 for your arch from a mirror.

Hint: dpkg -S libstdc++.so.6

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your apt somehow got corrupted.

You could try manually downloading the [apt for 8.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/apt) from the ubuntu package website and installing it with `sudo dpkg -i filename_of_the_package.deb`

Comment: I have tried that, didn't succeed...